# Azure VM creation date

Tags: azure

Is there any Management API to find Azure VM creation date? There is Get hosted service properties API for Cloud service creation date but we are not able to find out Azure VM creation date.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can see the creation date was included in disk name on the Dashboard.
   [image]
2. Also you could use Azure Powershell Command to retrieve this:

   ```
   Get-AzureVM -ServiceName myubuntu1 | Get-AzureOSDisk | select MediaLink
   ```

Answer (score 1):

We can retrieve operation system disk file creation time in Blob storage which equivalent to virtual machine creation time. see more https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/3da7750a-1a7d-4c62-b58a-a4b427b2520d/get-azure-vm-creationprovision-date

Answer (score 1):

2016 update: There still isn't a way to quickly get VM creation date in a reliable way (no, the date portion of the disk name is not reliable).

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a function for this sort of thing you may find useful.

The function only requires your tenantID and an identity that has the right permissions and will return the data you're after regarding creation date of Azure VMs, the resource groups they are in, OS and SKU.

Here is the function:

```
Function Get-AZVMCreated {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Function "Get-AZVMCreated" will connect to a given tenant and parse through the subscriptions and output Azure VM details based on creation date.

.DESCRIPTION
Author: Pwd9000 (Pwd9000@hotmail.co.uk)
PSVersion: 5.1

The user must specify the TenantId when using this function.
The function will request access credentials and connect to the given Tenant.
Granted the identity used has the required access permisson the function will parse through all subscriptions 
and gather data on Azure Vms based on the creation date.

.EXAMPLE
Get-AZVMCreated -TenantId "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"

.PARAMETER TenantId
A valid Tenant Id object. e.g: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" <String>
#>

[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True,
        ValueFromPipeline = $True,
        HelpMessage = 'Please specify the tenant id? e.g: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"')]
    [string]$TenantId
)

#------------------------------------------------Obtain Credentials for Session------------------------------------------------------------
$Credential = Get-Credential

#---------------------------------------------Get all Subscription Ids for given Tenant----------------------------------------------------
$SubscriptionIds = (Get-AzureRmSubscription -TenantId $TenantId).Id

#-------------------------------------------------Create Empty Table to capture data-------------------------------------------------------
$Table = @()

Foreach ($Subscription in $SubscriptionIds) {
    Write-Host "Checking Subscription: $Subscription. for any Azure VMs and their creation date. This process may take a while. Please wait..." -ForegroundColor Green

    $RMAccount = Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Credential -TenantId $TenantId -Subscription $subscription
    Get-AzureRmDisk | Where-Object {$_.TimeCreated -le (Get-Date)} |
            Select-Object Name, ManagedBy, Resourcegroupname, TimeCreated |
            ForEach-Object {
                Try {
                    $ErrName = $_.Name
                    $AzDiskManagedBy = $_.managedby | Split-path -leaf
                    $AzDiskManagedByRG = $_.ResourceGroupName
                    $CreationDate = $_.TimeCreated
                    $OS = (Get-AzurermVM -name $AzDiskManagedBy -ResourceGroup $AzDiskManagedByRG).StorageProfile.ImageReference.Offer
                    $SKU = (Get-AzurermVM -name $AzDiskManagedBy -ResourceGroup $AzDiskManagedByRG).StorageProfile.ImageReference.SKU
                    $Table += [pscustomobject]@{VMName = $AzDiskManagedBy; Created = $CreationDate; ResourceGroup = $AzDiskManagedByRG; OperatingSystem = $OS; SKU = $SKU}
                }
                Catch {
                    Write-Host "Cannot determine machine name associated with disk: [$ErrName]. Skipping drive-check for this item..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
                    Write-Host "Continue Checking Subscription: $Subscription. for any Azure VMs and their creation date. This process may take a while. Please wait..." -ForegroundColor Green
                }
            }
}
$UniqueVMs = $Table | Sort -Unique -Property VMName
$UniqueVMs
Write-Host "" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "Number of disks associated with VMs: $($Table.Count)" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "Number of disks unable to associate with VMs: $($ErrName.Count)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Write-Host "Number of unique Azure VMs associated with disks: $($UniqueVMs.Count)" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "Script finished.." -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

You can then call and use the function like this for example:

```
$TenantId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$AZVMsAll = Get-AZVMCreated -TenantId $TenantId | sort-object -property Created
$Win10 = $AZVMsAll | Where-Object {$_.SKU -like "*Windows-10*"} | sort-object -property Created
$Win8 = $AZVMsAll | Where-Object {$_.SKU -like "*Win81*"} | sort-object -property Created
$Win7 = $AZVMsAll | Where-Object {$_.SKU -like "*Win7*"} | sort-object -property Created
$Server2008R2 = $AZVMsAll | Where-Object {$_.SKU -like "*2008-R2*"} | sort-object -property Created
$Server2012R2 = $AZVMsAll | Where-Object {$_.SKU -like "*2012-R2*"} | sort-object -property Created
$Server2016 = $AZVMsAll | Where-Object {$_.SKU -like "*2016*"} | sort-object -property Created
$RHEL = $AZVMsAll | Where-Object {$_.OperatingSystem -like "*RHEL*"} | sort-object -property Created
$Ubuntu = $AZVMsAll | Where-Object {$_.OperatingSystem -like "*Ubuntu*"} | sort-object -property Created
$Centos = $AZVMsAll | Where-Object {$_.OperatingSystem -like "*Centos*"} | sort-object -property Created

$AZVMsAll
```

In the above example you can also call other versions of OS's using the variable defined e.g. For all Win7 machines you can call variable $Win7 etc etc etc...

Comment: Note: I would also recommend having some sort of naming convention for the AzureRmDisk "name" parameter of the VM to contain some sort of refference to the purpose of the disk, and filter on the OSDisk e.g: Where-Object { $_.name -like "\*osdisk*"} (add the filter on line 34 in the function). This will greatly reduce the function looking through all disks and will target the OS disk only which is what we are after.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Virtual Machines - Get Rest API in Azure to get all the details of the VM. It includes the creation date of Azure VM.

Rest API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual-machines/get?tabs=HTTP

Answer (score 0):

Use below az commands to get the disk creation date...From this OS Disk creation, we can find the VM provision date:

```
diskquery='[*].{Resourceid:id, name:name, timeCreated:timeCreated}'
az disk list --query "$diskquery"
```

Answer (score 0):

use below command

```
az vm list
```

This will list json data with fields and you can filter

```
date = vm['timeCreated']
```

//"timeCreated": "2022-06-24T14:13:00.326985+00:00",

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a way to get this via the Windows Azure APIs that I'm aware of.  Are you trying to remotely get this value, or get it for use on the instance?

If you are on the instance you might try to get it based on WMI.  Here it is in PowerShell, but you can adapt to C#, VB.NET, or another Scripting language that can get at the WMI info.

```
[reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("system.management")
$wmiSearch = new-object -type System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher -Arg "Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem"
$data = $wmiSearch.Get()
[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($data.InstallDate)
```

I tried this on an Azure VM and it returned basically the creation of the VM to me.  You might want to test this result over time though.  Also, this would only get you the time in which the VM was actually spun up.  So, if you have an instance A that is running along well, then the hard drive faults on it and the Fabric Controller moves the instance to another location in the DC and spins it back up then the install date will likely be the time it was moved.  This may be exactly what you are looking for, or maybe not depending on your requirements.