# All VM detail Created in a single Day

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I need to create a PS script which can give me a report how many azure VMs are created today or created on a particular day.
I don't find any information in terms of date and time by `get-azurevm` or `get-azurevm -servicename "testservice" -name "testvm"`
Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: I Think this has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849126/azure-vm-creation-date

Comment: My cloud service contains of more than 10 vm. Some are old some are new. I just want want to know which vm was created on which day and not the cloud service.